GitHub has lots of local commits waiting to be pushed to the master remote branch on Azure, but rules do not allow it
So I am using GitHub Desktop with a Git repository on Azure.
I have cloned the remote repo.
I create a new branch based on the master.
I publish the branch to the remote.
I add a file.
I commit those changes to the local branch.
I push the commits to the origin remote.
I switch back to the master branch in GitHub Desktop.
I merge the branch I just created into the master branch.
When I try and push the changes back to the master branch I get this message:
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)

To https://dev.azure.com/******************
[remote rejected]   master -> master (TF402455: Pushes to this branch are not permitted; you must use a pull request to update this branch.)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://dev.azure.com/*********************'

Which is fine as this rule has been setup on Azure.
I goto Azure DevOps and create a pull request.
The reviewer gets an email and approves the PR.
I then go and complete the merge into the master branch.
The issue I have is my GitHub Desktop client on my machine is building up more and more local commits on the master branch waiting to be pushed to the remote (which i cant do). It seems to have no knowledge of the pull requests being completed on Azure DevOps. I am not sure if I am missing something totally obvious, or if I somehow have to manually tell my local client that the pushes to the master have been taken care of (or maybe they haven't??). I am a little confused.
ScreenShot 1

A git fetch should make your local repo aware that PRs to master have been merged. But in case you've squashed your commits when completing the PR, you would indeed still have unpushed commits on your local branch (may or may not be the case, tell us more)

If I do a fetch from the master, all the changes remain outstanding: let me post an image of what i see: added a screenshot to the original posting

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To clarify from the above comment: how do I bring my local repository up to date if I cannot push my final commits to the master branch.

Since there are branch policies set on the master branch, you cannot directly push changes to it. You need to created a PR to merge changes from another branch to master.
When you make changes in the local repository, you should:

Create a new branch based on master.
Make changes on the new branch.
Push the new branch to the remote repository.
Create a PR in the remote repository to merge the changes from the new branch into master. Recommend using "Merge (no fast-forward)" as the merge method.
In the local repository, switch to master branch, then run git pull or git fetch to sync the latest changes from the remote master into the local master.

For your case, you can try to run git pull or git fetch in the local master branch to see if it can work. If it does not work, you might need to remove the local repository, and then clone the remote repository to local again.
